# can mysqldump on a large database be causing my long queries to hang?

Tags: mysql

I have a large database (approx 50GB). It is on a server I have little control over, but I know they are using mysqldump to do backups nightly.

I have a query that takes hours to finish. I set it to run, but it never actually finishes.

I've noticed that after the backup time, all the tables have a lock request (SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE in_use > 0; lists all tables).

The tables from my query have in_use = 2, all other tables have in_use = 1.

So... what is happening here?
a) my query is running normally, blocking the dump from happening. I should just wait?
b) the dump is causing the server to hang (maybe lack of memory/disk space?)
c) something else?

EDIT: using MyISAM tables

There is a server admin who is not very competent, but if I ask him specific things he does them. What should I get him to check?

EDIT: adding query

```
SELECT citing.article_id as citing, citing.year, r.id_when_cited, cited_issue.country
FROM isi_lac_authored_articles as citing # 1M records
        JOIN isi_citation_references r ON (citing.article_id = r.article_id) # 400M records
        JOIN isi_articles cited ON (cited.id_when_cited = r.id_when_cited) # 25M records
        JOIN isi_issues cited_issue ON (cited.issue_id = cited_issue.issue_id) # 1M records
```

This is what EXPLAIN has to say:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys                                                            | key                                   | key_len | ref                           | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cited_issue | ALL  | NULL                                                                     | NULL                                  | NULL    | NULL                          | 1156856 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | cited       | ref  | isi_articles_id_when_cited,isi_articles_issue_id                         | isi_articles_issue_id                 | 49      | func                          |      19 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r           | ref  | isi_citation_references_article_id,isi_citation_references_id_when_cited | isi_citation_references_id_when_cited | 17      | mimir_dev.cited.id_when_cited |       4 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | citing      | ref  | isi_lac_authored_articles_article_id                                     | isi_lac_authored_articles_article_id  | 16      | mimir_dev.r.article_id        |       1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

I actually don't understand why it needs to look at all the records in isi_issues table. Shouldn't it just be matching up by the isi_articles (cited) on issue_id? Both fields are indexed.

Comment: Kind of hard to tell here, but it sounds like this is more of a server issue and the backups may be causing the resources to diminish.  I would check into a analytic database like www.infobright.org though for queries that take that long to finish.

Comment: what can I ask the server admin to check? I don't think he'll install an analytic database...

Comment: i would first find out what kind of storage engine are they using MyIsam, InnoDB, ...  Second find out when the backups generally are done and not try to run your query at that time, get a benchmark for your query without that running

Comment: I've tried to set the query to run in the morning, and it is still not finished by the time the backup starts at 9pm... I'm querying tables with Millions of records and returning about 3M.

Comment: That kind of query should really be run inside of an analytic database or columnar database.  Your query could be spanning the entire disk.  Can you post the query.

Comment: @CraigTrombly just posted query and corresponding EXPLAIN

Comment: Are you trying to "invetigate" the data to do analytics or are you already knowing what you are looking for within the data? I am writing an article on investigative & iterative queries. The approach here is the issue. I would love to talk with you about this and hep you find the best solution for your task. My email address is in my profile. If you email me, I can respond back with contact info.

Comment: Can you change the data structure here at all? Are you manually running these queries and pulling the data into your environment or are you letting a process run that exports that data into some other file?

Comment: @CraigTrombly I just contacted you by email at the infobright.com address I found with Google.

Comment: I have replied already contacted you back via email.

Answer (score 3):

For a MySQL database of that size, you may want to consider setting up replication to a slave node, and then have your nightly database backups performed on the slave.

Comment: you'd recommend this even if we don't have many transactions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- some options to mysqldump will have the effect of locking all MyISAM tables while the backup is in progress, so that the backup is a consistent "snapshot" of a point in time.

InnoDB supports transactions, which make this unnecessary. It's also generally faster than MyISAM. You should use it. :)

Comment: but if I set my query to run before the backup, shouldn't my query lock out the backup until the query finishes? Its not a transactional database, its for analysis. I thought MyISAM was generally faster than InnoDB when you didn't have a lot of queries.

Comment: MyISAM is generally the same speed overall as InnoDB, or slower, on current versions of MySQL.